# Search worksheet with command button and textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you guys can help me.

my Manager asked me to create in excel a workbook whit a functionality to search on the click of a button. nothing I do works for some reason and would like to see if what she has asked is actually possible?

the idea is that I have 1 textbox where a text is entered, for example 11012587 then the search button is hit and it will search a hidden sheet for this reference. then another textbox will show instructions relating to this reference from that same hidden sheet.

nothing I do works and I have to admit I'm a bit of a noob at this so my codes that I've tried might be completely wrong.

looking forward to your replies :)

thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You say your code doesn't work, but what exactly happens? Please share your code so we can better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strSearchValue As String
    Dim rngPosition As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange '<- Change sheet name

        strSearchValue = "Test" '<- Change search text

        Set rngPosition = .Find(strSearchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngPosition Is Nothing Then '<- If search text found

            MsgBox rngPosition.Address '<- Messagew box with the address

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```